# Trigger an event when i scroll the scrollbar in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

i want to know the position of the chart when i move the scrollbar in the highchart . is there any scrollbar event associated in highchart .Please help .

Comment: Only `setExtremes` and `afterSetExtremes` handlers. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events).

Answer (score 0):

The [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events) does not show any event handling options for the scrollbar.

Let's take a look at the code in their [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/scrollbar/style/). Here is the SVG that renders the scrollbar itself.

```
<g class="highcharts-scrollbar" transform="translate(10,372)">
    <rect x="0" y="-0.5" fill="white" stroke="silver" stroke-width="1" 
          rx="7" ry="7" height="14" width="580"></rect>
    <rect y="0" height="14" fill="gray" rx="7" ry="7" x="358" 
          width="18"></rect>
    <path fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" 
          visibility="visible" 
          d="M 363.5 3.5 L 363.5 9.333333333333334 M 366.5 3.5 L 366.5 9.333333333333334 M 369.5 3.5 L 369.5 9.333333333333334"></path>
    <g>
        <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="15" height="15" strokeWidth="0" rx="7" ry="7" fill="gray"></rect>
        <path fill="yellow" d="M 8 4 L 8 10 5 7"></path>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(566,0)">
        <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="15" height="15" strokeWidth="0" rx="7" ry="7" fill="gray"></rect>
        <path fill="yellow" d="M 6 4 L 6 10 9 7"></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

The scrollbar position is the 2nd `<rect>` tag. You can use jQuery to retrieve the value of attribute x. In the example code, the position of x = 358 out of the maximum 580 space (the '' with which filling).